# setTheme(R.style.AppTheme) not working when creating APK

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, splash-screen

I display a splash screen on my Android app by using a theme for loading. In the MainActivity I change the theme using setTheme. It works when I build the app from Android Studio on the emulator (it compiles and runs). When I try to build an APK using Build->Build APKs, I get an error.

`E:\AndroidStudioProjects\gb\feature\src\main\java\com\zwsi\gb\feature\MainActivity.kt: (25, 20): Unresolved reference: style`

What is different when building APK vs. building an app?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.perrochon.gb">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <meta-data
            android:name="aia-compat-api-min-version"
            android:value="1"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme) // TODO switch back from the Launcher Theme, but this won't compile to APK
    // setTheme(R.style.AppTheme) works in Android Studio -> Emulator, but not when building APKs. Error is
    // E:\AndroidStudioProjects\gb\feature\src\main\java\com\zwsi\gb\feature\MainActivity.kt: (25, 20): Unresolved reference: style

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Edit: Adding build gradle files. I haven't really done anything with the gradel build files, they are the way Android Studio set them up.

build.gradle from gb

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle from gb\feature

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation project(':base')
implementation project(':gblib')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

build.gradle from gb\base

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
baseFeature true
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
api 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
application project(':app')
feature project(':feature')
}
```

build.gradle from gb\app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28



defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.zwsi.gb.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


}

buildTypes {
   release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation project(':feature')
implementation project(':base')
implementation project(':gblib')
}
```

I also have gblib directory with a library of non-Android code. build.gradle from gb\lib

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

sourceCompatibility = "6"
targetCompatibility = "6"
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
}
compileTestKotlin {
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
}
```

Comment: The difference is between `debug` and `release` build types. Where exactly is your `styles.xml`?

Comment: I think I am buidling debug APKs. That's what the files are named. I think what goes on the emulator is debug, too, no? styles is in E:\AndroidStudioProjects\gb\base\src\main\res\values\styles.xml (gb is project name). I was wondering about location of styles, and tried to put styles elsewhere, but couldn't make it work that way.

Comment: Note that the kotlin code that generates the problem is in a different directory. E:\AndroidStudioProjects\gb\feature\src\main\java\com\zwsi\gb\feature\MainActivity.kt

Comment: Ok - both are from `main`  but in different modules `base` and `feature` - how does `feature` module include `base`? build.gradle files please

Comment: Thanks @laalto for your help. I added the build.gradle files to the orginal question above. I don'

Comment: I added the build.gradle files to the orginal question above. They are mostly what AS set them up for initial tutorial. I have base for styles, and strings. Most of my code is in feature. I did create an additional directory gblib for code that is not Android specific.

Comment: Ok, nothing obviously wrong there. I have no hands-on experience with these `com.android.feature` modules and `feature` / `application` dependencies so I don't know how they affect the build process.